# mysql, I have two large fields, which when records are looped and displayed make site slow

Tags: php, mysql

My ISPs server uses MySQL.

I have a table which has a field with 2000 characters in it, I show about 20 records at a time on most pages and this I think causes the site to be slow.

I'd like to limit the characters to 450, I can do this in PHP, but I was wondering if I could do it in the query instead, e.g. left(english2000,450)  would that help ?

If so what would I use, I'm assume there isn't a left function.

Also I'd like to keep the name of the field in tact can I do ... left(english2000,450) as english200 ?  if not how ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try before you ask :-) `SELECT LEFT(english2000,450) AS english2000 FROM somewhere` should work fine.

Comment: -1 for `I'm assume there isn't a left function.`. What prevents you from at least trying? Not to mention documentation lookup. That's incredible laziness and ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [left()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) function in mysql:

```
SELECT LEFT(somefield, 450) AS somefield
```

Answer (score 10):

40 000 bytes would slow down a page? Most components on the web are far bigger than that, still maintaining a reasonable response time.

I do not think cutting your SQL response will help that much. Of course it doesn't mean either you or me is right, it means you have to **measure and see for yourself**.

You haven't defined 'slow' either, but I bet you'll be able to improve the response time the most if you precisely know what your bottleneck is.

Comment: I can't believe I see a sensible answer on stackoverflow

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Writing meaningfully is slow so most of the time it's not worth it. (Yea, the problem of the fastest gun.) Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to have one more column that contains only first 450 charatcers of english2000 column, this will improve speed!

Answer (score -1):

Table Geography
region_name store_name
East    Boston
East    New York
West    Los Angeles
West    San Diego
Example 1:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(store_name, 3) 
FROM Geography 
WHERE store_name = 'Los Angeles';
```

Result:

's Angeles'

Example 2:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(store_name,2,4) 
FROM Geography 
WHERE store_name = 'San Diego';
```

Result:

'an D'

http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-substring.html